# Chrome hiding background image with autofills

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Hi guys Im working on basic signup and signin forms.In my input fields I consist of background image and white color.In chrome autofill was replacing my background image and color with pale yellow color.For this I have searched and found out few lines of code....

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
background-color: #FAFFBD !important;
  }
```

This was making my backgroundcolor to display...but Unable to show the backgroundimage in input field.Can I get few bits of code to show the background image when autofill in chrome.

```
 input#email {
background: url("~mail.png") no-repeat scroll  16px 11px #FFFFFF;
background-size: 20px 20px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Need to show your css and html if you want a proper answer.

Comment: I have added a snippet

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can do this in 2 ways

1: put a z-index field on your css to your background image so that it overlaps whatever is overlapping it at the moment

```
z-index: 999 //for example
```

2: Or make your image have top-margin to make way for the input field's autofill space:

```
margin-top: 25px;
```

Comment: sorry just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try the change with jQuery:

```
if ($.browser.webkit) {
    //$('input[name="password"]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
    $('input[name="password"]').attr('background-image', 'src');
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: you case give an absolute div with background image behind the input and give a background none, transparent for the input, to display the background image, but i don't sure if the background image will be viewed with auto fills!